# Angular/UI-Router - How Can I Update The URL Without Refreshing Everything?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to both Angular and the ui-router.  When someone selects a model and my controller performs a standard SHOW method, I simply want to update the URL to include the model's ID without refreshing the page, and continue on with my original view.  I'm not sure how to do this...

```
$stateProvider
        .state('citylist', {
          url: "/",
          templateUrl: "views/index.html"
        })
        .state('cityshow', {
          url: "/city/:id",
          templateUrl: "views/index.html"
        })

angular.module('app.system').controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'Global', 'Cities', '$stateParams', '$location', function ($scope, Cities, $stateParams, $location) {

    $scope.loadTown = function(id) {
        Cities.get({id: id }, function(city) {
             $scope.city = city
             // Change URL
             // Do things within the same view...
        });
    };
});

<button ng-click="loadTown(123456)">Chicago</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code snippets you've used are a bit far from the correct *ui-router* settings. I would suggest to you, check this demo application: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/1. Here we can see how the *List* is "fixed" while *Detail* is changed without any page refresh.

The code of this example download here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/master/sample.

What should help a lot to understand HOW TO *(except the [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference))* was this code snippet: **[state.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/contacts/contacts.js)**. Load the demo, read through this commented explanation. And `ui-router` will make sense...

Comment: Im sure you have seen this: http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router Radim's advise is good. Most of the jsfiddles, plunkers and articles are already outdated and though there is nothing really hard about the ui-router, it takes a while to realize unless you find the correct source.

Comment: @radim: does this really solve the original question - namely how to update a model and a URL, but without refreshing a view? That's the question I have reasked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467170/angular-ui-router-update-url-without-view-refreshes

Answer (score 1):

In essence, what you want to do is **not** to put the city code in the ui-view and/or not to use a template with this view. As a result, none of the DOM will get changed but the URL will. This is discussed more fully on [Angular-ui.router: Update URL without view refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467170/angular-ui-router-update-url-without-view-refresh)