# simple ui-routes, explanation please

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I came to know that ui-roues are much powerful and advantageous than ngRoutes, recently. So I satrted studiing the ui-routing feature from `http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-router.html` . BUt could not undersatnd withh the examples they have given especially from "Multiple named views" in `http://jsfiddle.net/jwebe0pe/9vH9Z/`, as they have given the explanation using d3.js, which I do not know.

1. I request here you guys, to give me a simple jsfiddle explantion, about how to implement Multiple view ui-route
2. What is the importance of

> ```
> $stateProvider.state('admin', {
>         abstract: true,
>         url: '/admin',
>         template: '<div ui-view></div>'
>       }).state('admin.index', {
>         url: '/index',
>         template: 'Admin index'
>       }).state('admin.users', {
>         url: '/users',
>         template: '<ul>...</ul>'
>       });
> ```

admin, admin.index and admin.users, in the code above and when will be used.

3 Could not able to understand the abstract: true/false concept.

Please clarify me in the above points.

Hope you guys help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you could do is to go through all the links mentioned in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20581135/1679310):

- [example app](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/1) by ui-router team
- [source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/master/sample) of that example
- and essential [**`state.js`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/contacts/contacts.js) definition, one of the best documented codes ever
- plus the [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Here I created [another example](http://plnkr.co/edit/I0BJ09BxR7nG9kZDeEIv?p=preview) with some master layout introducing TOP, LEFT, MAIN areas as separted multi-views.

That Layout state would be defined as this:

```
.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
      '@' : {
        templateUrl: 'layout.html',
        controller: 'IndexCtrl'
      },
      'top@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.top.html',},
      'left@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.left.html',},
      'main@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.main.html',},
    },
  })
```

the core template injected into **index.html** element `<div ui-view></div>`:

```
<div>
  <section class="top">
    <div ui-view="top"></div> // TOP here
  </section>
  
  <section class="middle">
    
    <section class="left">
      <div ui-view="left"></div> // LEFT here
    </section>
    
    <section class="main">
      <div ui-view="main"></div> // MAIN here
    </section>
  
  </section>
</div>
```

So we can see, that one state *(`'index'` above)* has one master view (layout) and also other views, injected into that layout template, using the absolute view naming:

- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) *(cite:)*

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.

I.e. the part of state definition: `'top@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.top.html',},` says:

- inject `tpl.top.html` template into the view named **`top`**
- search for that name inside of a state named **`index`**
- these information together: top + index == **`'top@index'`** view name

Observe the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I0BJ09BxR7nG9kZDeEIv?p=preview) - to see that in action...in very simplified example....

EXTEND: to give some more explanation to the extended question

What is abstract state? I.e state marked as `abstract: true`...

Like in any other languague (C#, Java) it is a standard state, which cannot be instantiated, reached directly. It is always a **`parent`** state, intended to handle some basic functionality. Namely:

- views do profit from [Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only):

> Keep in mind that scope properties only inherit down the state chain if the views of your states are nested. Inheritance of scope properties has nothing to do with the nesting of your states and everything to do with the nesting of your views (templates).
>
> It is entirely possible that you have nested states whose templates populate ui-views at various non-nested locations within your site. In this scenario you cannot expect to access the scope variables of parent state views within the views of children states.

so, the parent controller can be provided with some resolver settings, it can handle authorization, it can load data... Simply, as a parent, it can do lot of common stuff for children, while it cannot be reached directly

- it also can make templating easier. because it the abstract parent would containt e.g. template.layout... children can use realtive view naming.

So, abstract is a feature. Feature very similar to standard inehritance...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks like you have given all the steps /links, which will help in understanding the topic, Thanks for that, Have modified my question, can you please looks again and help me little further, Will mark your answer, right now :)

Comment: There are two main points of abstract: parent implementation like in C#, Java... simplify view nesting with relative naming. BUT for sure, go through all resources I gave you. DO IT. then observe example and play with... you will never leave `ui-router` then