# what does abstract:true do in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Sorry my question may seems duplicate beacuse i'm learning Angular JS with some downloaded template but i dint get anything what i exactly need with my searching.

what does abstract: true means?

the main question is  .otherwise('/app/dashboard');  taking me to  partials/app_dashboard.html  if i had mentioned /dashboard in otherwise it should take me there but why /app/dashboard landing me in partials/app_dashboard.html. does abstract: true have any effect in otherwise?

header div, container div(ui-view) and footer div was placed in app.html

$urlRouterProvider

```
        .otherwise('/app/dashboard');
    $stateProvider            
        .state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/app',
            templateUrl: 'partials/app.html'
        })
        .state('app.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'partials/app_dashboard.html'
        })
        .state('app.ui', {
            url: '/ui',
            template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-up"></div>'
        })
```

Comment: Check this answer with detailed explanation and examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25499004/1679310

Comment: Read the docs first - it's clearly explained there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> abstract - {boolean=} - An abstract state will never be directly activated, but can provide inherited properties to its common children states.

From [ui-router docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

Comment: thanks for reply @rawry, what about .otherwise('/app/dashboard');

Comment: if no state or url matches, then it will use the url specified in .otherwise(), its like a default, if nothing matches i show the home page

Comment: @rawry can we set the .otherwise state to the abstract state?