# Changing Navigation Menu using UI-Router in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to build a navigational menu like any social networking site i.e. If i'm  `logged-Out` i Can see the `input fields` asking for `Username` and `Password` but if I'm `logged-In` then i get to see my profile ,settings ,etc.

I'm trying to do the same thing but Cannot thing of an approach to this i Just need to know the way i can do this. I know the use case in which angular directive are used like `ng-if` ,etc but i'm thinking of using partials in some way.

I'm Using `AngularJs` with `UI-Router`.

Comment: You should start with reading docs, observing the sample/example app and the you will see that this is a task for a multi-view feature. Here you can find some [links](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25499004/1679310) where to start

Comment: i know the use of `ng-*` directives but i want to use partials(if i can)

Comment: Have you seen my link? it is about `ui-router`, the really only reasonable tool for state/views managemetn... I **never** mentioned any `ng-*`...

Comment: @RadimKöhler i have Read the  link that you suggested but still couldnt find the solution

Comment: @AnkitLadhania if I understood correctly you want to built a menu. Can you please point out what the problem is?

Comment: @Dalorzo I want to make the template of the menu dynamic by using partials i.e.  just like facebook or github if the user is not logged in i will show them the `Please login or Sign Up` on tab but if they are logged in i will show them different tabs related to user. I want to do it in SPA without reloading a page or refreshing.

Comment: @AnkitLadhania what is wrong with `ng-if`?

Comment: @Dalorzo as per me it can be defined in a state. can it? and as i'm using ui-router i think it is better to do everything in same follow. What do you think?

Comment: @AnkitLadhania, glad, really glad that you've went through resources mentioned above. Really good. So, to speead up your ui-router usage, I've created an example for you. Hope it will help some how ;) Enjoy the amazing lib ui-router ;)

Comment: If that helped anyhow, awesome ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ui-router` solution could be like in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DdoNU67QCWB0izvoKFvQ?p=preview), I've created to show **the `ui-router` way**. There is no need to use some view rendering directives ala `ng-if`, `ng-show`... which in fact moves the logic from business into the view.

The [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DdoNU67QCWB0izvoKFvQ?p=preview) shows a comprehensive design, with redirections for unauthorized users, as well to grant the public accesss to anybody, supporting log on/off in one view, etc.

Better solution is to profit from built-in features of the `ui-router`, e.g.:

#### [Templates](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates) *(let me cite:)*

> **TemplateUrl**
> ... `templateUrl` can also be a function that returns a url. **It takes one preset parameter, `stateParams`, which is NOT injected.**
>
> **TemplateProvider**
> Or you can use a **template provider** function which **can be injected, has access to locals**, and must return template HTML...

So, what we can see in our example. Firstly there is a root state with two views, one of them is standard anchor, for all main child unnamed views `ui-view=""`

```
$stateProvider
.state('root', {
  abstract: true,
  views: {
    '': {templateUrl: 'tpl.root.html', },
    'loginfo@root': {
      templateProvider: templateSelector,
      controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    }
  }
})
```

where the `templateSelector` would be like this:

```
var templateSelector = function($http, UserService) 
{
  var templateName = UserService.isLogged
    ? "tpl.loggedin.html"
    : "tpl.loggedoff.html"
    ;

  return $http
    .get(templateName)
    .then(function(tpl){
      return tpl.data;
    });
};
```

Relying on simple setting in this example:

```
.factory('UserService', function() {
  return {
    isLogged: false,
  };
})
```

And that's it, we do have two templates:

- "tpl.loggedin.html"
- "tpl.loggedoff.html"

The remaining stuff is pretty expectable, state definitions, some redirection on unauthorized access... please observe the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DdoNU67QCWB0izvoKFvQ?p=preview).

which are interchanged based on the fact if user is logged on or off

Check the solution in this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DdoNU67QCWB0izvoKFvQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the following angular directives: [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow), [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

Check in your controller if the user has signed in successfully and assign this value a ($scope) variable and use this as a condition to either show or hide certain elements of your navigation bar.