# Apply condition on templateUrl in config while routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, user-experience, angular-translate

I'm using ui-router and developed a multi-lingual website using angular-translate
but currently I'm stuck where I want such scenario:

1. There will be 2 template for a single page one will be normal version which is would be English and working as normal site and second template would be consisting of `translate=""` attribute, in other words fully translated page. But I'm willing if I could have conditions while routing so this would resolve my issue.
   Looking at code could make it easier for you to understand.

Currently my code looks like:

```
.state('whoweAre', {
            url: '/about-us',
            templateUrl: 'templates/whoweAre/whoweAre.html', 
            controller: 'whoweAreCtrl'
        }
    )
```

but now currently I'm want something like

```
    .state('whoweAre', {
            url: '/about-us',
            templateUrl: function(isTranslated){
             if(isTranslated){
              return "templates/translated/whoweAre/whoweAre.html";
             }
             else{
               return "templates/whoweAre/whoweAre.html";
             }
            }, 
            controller: 'whoweAreCtrl'
        }
    )
```

but this doesn't seems to be working and I have this `isTranslated` variable in app.js and I can't access it in config (routes.js) file for me.
Any work around related to this would be great.
I'm using this because when user arrives for a first time angular translate text seems to be empty and tags appears with empty tags which is leading towards bad UX.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks !

Comment: You should get the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/33838313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I found this way useful. Thanks folks for all your help.

```
templateProvider:
  function(AppService) {
    if(AppService.getLocal("language").locale != 'en' )
    return "translated template url";
    else
    return "normal page"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find current state and set the template dynamically in **app.js**

In your **app.js** check the state

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next) {

                if(next.name=="whoweAre" && isTranslated)
                {
                  next.templateUrl="templates/translated/whoweAre/whoweAre.html";
                }
                else if(next.name=="whoweAre" && !isTranslated)
               {
                  next.templateUrl="templates/whoweAre/whoweAre.html";
               }
```