# ui-router nested views, correct use

Tags: view, angular-ui-router

i try to use ui-router and the states. I will want understand the correct use.

i have build a layout with nested views and now i want navigate into my layout.

layout is similar to frame and i want change only the right frame, but it's possibile?

[image]

for show view 1 i must build a state (with all structure menu,container,etc....), now if i want show the views 2 i must build another state?

Comment: As shown in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310) (I gave you previously) - we need two states... if we want to use native UI-Router behaviour. And the second state would have some changing param then... which is part of ui-sref and that forces only the substate change... or?

Comment: the answer is no, is not possibile. I must use 2 states...correct?

Comment: YES. Two states are "the intended way, built into UI-Router". Please, do not take it as a problem. It is in fact easy to implement and sooner you will like it. I am sure ;)