# In Angularjs with ui-router how to change hash without reloading controller but keeping subviews routing enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

**In short**: my [demo](http://s.codepen.io/M1k3l/debug/EKEQLw), how to have subviews? (without reloading page)

**Longer**:

I'm using [snapscroll](https://github.com/joelmukuthu/angular-snapscroll) to provide different screens effect ([demo](http://joelmukuthu.github.io/angular-snapscroll/)). This directive doesn't support by default ui-router so I had to do it myself.

When you move the mouse wheel `beforeSnap` event event is triggered. I call ui-router  `$state.go` to change URL hash. I don't reload the controller.

```
$scope.beforeSnap = function (snapIndex) {
    $state.go('view' + snapIndex,{},{
        notify:false,
        reload:false, 
        location:'replace', 
        inherit:true
    });
};
```

Routing is like

```
.state('main', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/screens.html',
    controller: 'mainCtrl'
})
.state('view0', {
    url: '/green',
    templateUrl: 'views/screens.html',
    controller: 'mainCtrl',
    params: {'color': 'green', 'screenIndex': 0}
})
[...]
```

views/screens.html:

```
<div fit-window-height="" snapscroll="" snap-index="snapIndex" before-snap="beforeSnap(snapIndex)">
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="blue">
        <!-- How to enable these subviews? -->
        <!-- <a ui-sref="view0.a">Go to view0.a</a> -->
        <!-- <a ui-sref="view0.b">Go to view0.b</a> -->
        <div ui-view="view1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="yellow">
        <div ui-view="view3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see a [codepen](http://codepen.io/M1k3l/pen/EKEQLw) and a [demo](http://s.codepen.io/M1k3l/debug/EKEQLw).

The issue is that I want to have subviews in some "screens" (colours divs), e.g: view1 and view3.
But I don't know how to do it without reloading the whole page. Subviews like:

- /view1/a
- /view1/b
- /view3/a
- /view3/b
- /view3/c

Besides, I think screens would be better/cleaner being children of main main.view0, main.view1, etc.

I read about [multiple named views in ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) and [nested states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800644/nested-states-or-views-for-layout-with-leftbar-in-ui-router?rq=1) without success.