# ui-router angular master detail view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get the userlist [master] and user details[detail] on the same page.

https://plnkr.co/edit/EKY2pztGkKXUuQIyefUY?p=preview

module and configuration.

```
var myModule = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);  

myModule.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('user', {
      url : '/users',
      templateUrl:'users.html',
      controller : 'usersController'
  })
  .state('user.details', {
      url : '/:id',
      templateUrl:'users.html',
      controller : 'usersControllerDetail'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/users");

});


myModule.controller('usersController' ,  function($scope){
  $scope.users = [{username : 'manish', id : 1}, { username : 'kaustubh', id :2} ]
});

myModule.controller('usersControllerDetail' ,  function($scope, $stateParams){
  console.log($stateParams.id);
});
```

when ever I click on the user in the master list , master list is rendered twice on scree.

can you please let me know where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is adjusted and [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sFSY49eIDY7aIUsjmG3s?p=preview)

Just use different template for a child

```
.state('user.details', {
      url : '/:id',
      //templateUrl:'users.html',
      templateUrl:'details.html',
      controller : 'usersControllerDetail'
});
```

this could be the template

```
<div>

 <div ui-view>
  <h3>current state name: <var>{{$state.current.name}}</var></h3>


  <h5>params</h5>
  <pre>{{$stateParams | json}}</pre>
  <h5>state</h5>
  <pre>{{$state.current | json}}</pre>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can do that, but for now I want to do it in single page.. see this http://embed.plnkr.co/DBSbiV/App.js  , but not sure how to do this with ui-router

Comment: single page.. is not a single view (templateUrl). UI-Router is there not for making reuse of templates (while that is possible as well) but for splitting stuff into states with their own (unique) views/templates. So, what I showed you is THE WAY. Other words... reuse of templates will REUSE the templates. and what you see in parent you will see twice, if a child will come.

Comment: Please, also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310 to see the essence of views, named views and absolute name usage.. that is the essence of the UI-Router, good luck sir ;)

Comment: Thanks again. good luck sir [when recruiter says that... they never call me back..lol]