# Angular ui-router nested view routers not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Why this routes not working? How to force this code work? How to implement layouts work in angular-ui-router? Please help resolve this problem.

```
$stateProvider
    .state( 'layout', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        views: {
            'layout': { templateUrl: 'template/layout.html' },
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'template/header.html',
                controller: 'HeaderController'
            },
            'sidebar': { templateUrl: 'template/sidebar.template.html' }
        }
    } )
    .state( 'layout.home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'main@layout.home': { templateUrl: 'template/main.html' }
        }
    }
);
```

layout.html

```
<main class="layout">
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div ui-view="main"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

index.html

```
<div ui-view="layout"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
.state( 'layout', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '',
    views: {
        'layout': { templateUrl: 'template/layout.html' },
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'template/header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderController'
        },
        //'sidebar': { templateUrl: 'template/sidebar.template.html' }
        'sidebar@layout': { templateUrl: 'template/sidebar.template.html' }
    }
} )
.state( 'layout.home', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
        //'main@layout.home': { templateUrl: 'template/main.html' }
        'main': { templateUrl: 'template/main.html' }
    }
}
```

The parent *state* 'layout' - is now targeting `'sidebar@layout'` - using **absolute naming**, to find a template inside of the *'template/layout.html'*

The child view is simply using parents target 'main' so we do not need absolute naming. And if we want, it would be just

```
'main@layout': { templateUrl: 'template/main.html' }
```

because we target parent's 'layout' target `ui-view="main"`

Working example could be found here (with some more details)

- [Nested states or views for layout with leftbar in ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310)

Comment: Great to see that, sir! Enjoy UI-Router ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state( 'layout', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        views: {
            'layout': { 
                templateUrl: 'template/layout.html' 
            }
        }
    } )
    .state( 'layout.home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'main': { 
                templateUrl: 'template/main.html' 
            },
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'template/header.html',
                controller: 'HeaderController'
            },
            'sidebar': {
                templateUrl: 'template/sidebar.template.html' 
            }
        }
    }
);
```