# Are there any examples showcasing 3 level nesting using angular 1.4?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been studying ui-router for angular 1.4 at 'https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views', but I can't find an example that showcases having a child within a child... I mean without the `ui-router.stateHelper`, as I would much rather use the dot notation for this. So for example.. is the following possible?

```
$stateProvider
  .state('index', {})
  .state('index.contacts', {})
  .state('index.contacts.search', {})
```

Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you'd like to see.. but e.g. here is three level answer with working plunker http://stackoverflow.com/a/28061287/1679310

Comment: Thank you.. I'll investigate it!

Comment: There is no extra requirement for additional layers, just add the 3rd layer like how you add 2nd layer. Keep in mind you need a `ui-view` in 2nd layer so your 3rd layer content has a "window" to display.

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much...