# Angular Digest cycle being ran but ng-bind value not updating

Tags: angularjs, typescript, state, angular-ui-router

I have a parent view that contains a navbar, and inside of that view I have a `<div ui-view>` element which renders whatever child view I'm on.

I want to conditionally show/hide the navbar within the parent view, based on the route of the child view. Right now, I have this:

```
<nav ng-show="!vm.hideNavbar">
```

The first time my app is loaded, `vm.hideNavbar` is set to true and this works as expected.

After `vm.hideNavbar` is changed to false, the bound value is not updated. It is still `true`.

Every controller in my app extends this `BaseController`:

```
export class BaseController {
        public hideNavbar: boolean;

        constructor(public $scope: IBaseScope, private $state: ng.ui.IStateService) {
            if ($state.current.url === '/login') {
                this.hideNavbar = true;
            } else {
                this.hideNavbar = false;
            }
            $scope.vm = this;
        }
 }
```

So, everytime a new controller is loaded, it calls the constructor for `BaseController` and conditionally sets `$scope.vm.hideNavbar`. If I immediately run `$scope.$apply()` at the end of this constructor, angular throws errors saying the digest cycle is already being ran.

So, the digest cycle is being ran, but the value in my view is not being updated. My only thought is that I have instantiated more than one copy of the `BaseController` since my initial controller and the controller I navigated to both extend this controller. So, now, my bound value of `vm.hideNavbar` is still looking at the old controller.

Am I on the right track with this? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: this is a pitfall of using `vm` for every controller.  the child controllers are setting their own `hideNavbar` property, which is not the same as setting the `hideNavbar` property of the parent controller.  unless you can create unique names for each controller, you will probably end up needing to use a `$broadcast` or `$emit` to resolve this.

Comment: make boolean to nested object, like `this.navbar.status = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would suggest to go with **`view inheritance`** *(not `controller`, not `state`)*. Check more details here:

- [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)
- [How to inherit resolve data in ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26513746/1679310)

#### There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/iCcyvjZ26Et5UPmkttbR?p=preview)

What we would need is a `'root'` state. It will be the **super parent** of any other `state` *(states family)*. This could be the state definition:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('root', {
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'layout.tpl.html',
      controller: MyNamespace.RootCtrl,
  })

  .state('login', {
      parent: "root",
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: MyNamespace.LoginCtrl,
  })
  .state('home', {
      parent: "root",
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: MyNamespace.HomeCtrl,
  })
```

even some other state hierarchy will start with that `'root'` state:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('parent', {
      parent: "root",
      url: "/parent",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: MyNamespace.ParentCtrl
  })
  .state('parent.child1', { 
      url: "/child1",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: MyNamespace.Child1Ctrl
  })
  .state('parent.child2', { 
      url: "/child2",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: MyNamespace.Child2Ctrl
  })
```

We can see many **`controllers:...`** being defined, and here they are:

```
module MyNamespace {
    // the real SUPER parent of all states
    // but it is about VIEW inheritance (its $scope)
    // not about controller hierarchy
    export class RootCtrl extends BaseController {
    }

    export class HomeCtrl extends BaseController {
    }
    export class LoginCtrl extends BaseController {
    }
    export class ParentCtrl extends BaseController {
    }
    export class Child1Ctrl extends BaseController {
    }
    export class Child2Ctrl extends BaseController {
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the snippet comment - there is inheritance, but just on a code level. The passed `$scope` is inherited by view hierarchy.

The first controller in the view hierarchy is `RootCtrl`  which will in fact be the only, who will assign (create) the shared reference model **`rootSetting : {}`**

And they all derive from this one controller base:

```
module MyNamespace {
    export interface IRootSetting {
        hideNavbar: boolean;
    }
    export interface IMyRootScope extends ng.IScope {
        rootSetting: IRootSetting
    } 
    export interface IBaseScope extends IMyRootScope {

    }
    export class BaseController {
        public hideNavbar: boolean;
        static $inject = ['$scope', '$state'];

        constructor(public $scope: IBaseScope, 
                 protected $state: ng.ui.IStateService) {

                  // will be in fact assigned in the RootCtrl only
                  // all others (children) will get that reference
                  // via scope inheritance
                  $scope.rootSetting = $scope.rootSetting || {hideNavbar: false}; 

            if ($state.current.url === '/login') {
                this.$scope.rootSetting.hideNavbar = true;
            } else {
                this.$scope.rootSetting.hideNavbar = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Having that in place, with this root template:

```
<div>      
  <div ng-if="!rootSetting.hideNavbar"> 
   ... // navbar
  </div>      

  <div ui-view="">
      // standard content of child views
  </div>      
</div>
```

We can see, that here we evaluate the shared reference model **`rootSetting`** and its property `hideNavbar`

This is the real advantages of **`view inheritance`** coming with `UI-Router`.

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iCcyvjZ26Et5UPmkttbR?p=preview)