# UI-Router parent controller doesn't initiate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I'm using AngularJs UI-Router for my app, but I'm with a problem where the parent's controller isn't initiated.

This is my state structure:

```
.state('main', {
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'MainController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        config: function($timeout){
            return $timeout(function() {
                return console.log('loaded')
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
})
.state('home', {
    parent: 'main',
    url: '/Home',
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'view/home.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('contact', {
    parent: 'main',
    url: '/Contact',
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'view/contact.html',
        }
    }
})
```

The template home.html and contact.html are displaying on the view just fine. But inside the `MainController` I have just a console.log but it doesn't appear on the console.

If I make some changes, I can make it work. This is the working example:

```
.state('main', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'main': {
            template: '<div ui-view="content"></div>',
            controller: 'MainController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        }
    }
[...code...]

.state('home', {
    parent: 'main',
    url: '/Home',
    views: {
        'content': {
[...code...]
```

This way, everything works as expected, The view appear and the console from the controller also appear.

But it doesn't seem "right" because I need to create a template just to hold the child states.

Is there a way to make it work with the first option?

Comment: i've had problems using `controllerAs` try to use `controller: MainController as vm`

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval Since i was using the controller just for tests and to print a console, i tired to use it just as `controller: 'MainController'`, without the controllerAs, but got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to answer:

> ... Is there a way to make it work with the first option?

Have to say: **NO**. The point is:

> #### [Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only)
>
> Keep in mind that scope properties only inherit down the state chain if the views of your states are nested. Inheritance of scope
>   properties has nothing to do with the nesting of your states and
>   everything to do with the nesting of your views (templates).
>
> It is entirely possible that you have nested states whose templates populate ui-views at various non-nested locations within
>   your site. In this scenario you cannot expect to access the scope
>   variables of parent state views within the views of children states.

So, what happened is - the child state **`views: {}`** definition:

```
.state('contact', {
    parent: 'main',    
    views: {
        'content@': {
    ...
```

... forced child to skip parent view. **Not parent state**. It **skips a parent view**. There is no parent view, from which it could inherit the $scope.

The view of a child state *'contact'*, is injected directly into root (index.html) `ui-view="content"`, it will not trigger parent view...

So, use the second approach, which is absolutely correct, to achieve what is exepected

Check also these for farther details and working examples:

- [How to inherit resolve data in ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26513746/1679310)
- [Nested states or views for layout with leftbar in ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310)

Comment: I knew about the inheritance hierarchy, but I tought it was only applied to the resolve data, not to all views and controllers. Thanks for the great answer explaning what is actually happening!