# AngularJS ui-router not behaving with nested url as I would expect

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following working code using ui-router that does not have any nesting:

```
           state('speaker', {
                url: '/speaker/:id',
                templateUrl: 'app/speakers/speaker-detail.html',
                controller: 'SpeakerDetailController as vm',
                resolve: {
                    speakerResourceService: 'speakerResourceService',
                    speaker: function(speakerResourceService,$stateParams) {
                        return speakerResourceService.get({id: $stateParams.id}).$promise;
                    }
                }
            }).
```

I've tried to pull it apart as is below.  It kind of works but the controller never gets called.

```
           state('speaker', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/speaker',
                templateUrl: 'app/speakers/speaker-detail.html'
            }).
            state('speaker.id', {
                parent: 'speaker',
                url: '/:id',
                templateUrl: 'app/speakers/speaker-detail.html',
                controller: 'SpeakerDetailController as vm',
                resolve: {
                    speakerResourceService: 'speakerResourceService',
                    speaker: function(speakerResourceService,$stateParams) {
                        return speakerResourceService.get({id: $stateParams.id}).$promise;
                    }
                }
            }).
```

All hints are welcome.

Comment: and what is "not behaving as you would expect"?

Comment: Controller is not called in second code snippet.  Template renders bit with no expressions set because controller not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u96ir5cXwJtBb8DXkv0s?p=preview). What we need here is a **target for a child** - inside of the **parent**:

```
.state('speaker', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/speaker',
  //templateUrl: 'app/speakers/speaker-detail.html'
  template: "<div ui-view></div>"
}) 
.state('speaker.id', {
  parent: 'speaker',
  url: '/:id',
  //templateUrl: 'app/speakers/speaker-detail.html',
  template: "<div>this is a child state inside of a prent ui-view"
   + "<pre>{{$stateParams | json }}</pre>"
   + " <pre>{{$state.current | json }}</pre></div>",
  controller: 'SpeakerDetailController as vm',
  resolve: {
    speakerResourceService: 'speakerResourceService',
    speaker: function(speakerResourceService, $stateParams) {
      return 1;
      //return speakerResourceService.get({ id: $stateParams.id }).$promise;
    }
  }
});
```

So, what happened? Instead of this:

```
// parent
.state('speaker', {
    templateUrl: 'app/speakers/speaker-detail.html'
    ...
// child
.state('speaker.id', {
    templateUrl: 'app/speakers/speaker-detail.html',
    ...
```

where we have the same templates for parent and child - we need to create an anchor/target ... inside of a parent.. where the nested/child view will be placed:

```
// parent
.state('speaker', {
    // this does not have a target
    // templateUrl: 'app/speakers/speaker-detail.html'
    // this will instruct UI-Router where to inject child
    template: "<div ui-view></div>"
    ...
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u96ir5cXwJtBb8DXkv0s?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Radim.  Your extra effort here to figure out what was wrong and explain it so clearly is hugely helpful.  If I could +10 I would.

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow :) Enjoy awesome UI-Router :)

Comment: Radim, on a related note, I've been struggling with solving AngularJS problems like the above.  Is there any guidance on how to solve problems like this? It seems that someplace, I should be able to discover that the ui-view is not being found.  I've found angular debugging hard. Mostly solve by inspection and posting.  Any hints are hugely appreciated.

Comment: The way I learned UI-Router was by observing the sample app and reading the wiki. And I played with it - a lot. [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20581135/1679310) I named all the resources - mostly the **state.js**. This is the most amazing piece of code and documentation in one place - I've ever met. And of course, do not hesitate to search or ask here (some people do down vote) some other will gladly assist... I am sure ;) Good luck with UI-Router

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the `controller` property to `controllerAs: 'vm'`

See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Additionally, you need to make sure you have `ngRoute` inlcuded in your module and the route scripts installed in your app. I'm assuming you've done this since it 'kind of works'.

Also, I would double-check the version you are using to make sure it's kosher with the info I'm providing (which is assuming you are using version 1.3.6).

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: I'm confident my controller as syntax is good.  It works in first code snippet no problem with that syntax.  Same regarding ngRoute

Comment: because, you are using the ui-router and @caseybaggz routeProvider (url-router) which is built-in with angular. and he is talking about syntax which is routerProvider specific.

Comment: thanks cbass but I think the down votes are on my question and not caseybaggz's comment.