# Angular-ui.router: Update URL without view refresh

Tags: angularjs, seo, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I have an Angular SPA that presents a variety of recommendation lists, and a Google Map of locations, based on different cuts of some restaurant data (see [m.amsterdamfoodie.nl](http://m.amsterdamfoodie.nl)). I want each of these lists to have their own URL. In order for Google to crawl the different lists I use `<a>` tags for the offcanvas navigation.

At present the `<a>` tag causes a view refresh, which is very noticeable with the map.

- I can prevent this using `ng-click` and `$event.preventDefault()` (see code snippets below), but then I need to implement a means of updating the browser URL.
- But in trying Angular's `$state` or the browser's `history.pushstate`, I end up triggering state changes and the view refresh...!

My question is therefore **how can I update a model and the URL, but without refreshing the view?**  (See also [Angular/UI-Router - How Can I Update The URL Without Refreshing Everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578840/angular-ui-router-how-can-i-update-the-url-without-refreshing-everything))

I have experimented with a lot of approaches and currently have this html

```
<a href="criteria/price/1" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="main.action($event)">Budget</a>
```

In the controller:

```
this.action = ($event) ->
    $event.preventDefault()
    params = $event.target.href.match(/criteria\/(.*)\/(.*)$/)

    # seems to cause a view refresh
    # history.pushState({}, "page 2", "criteria/"+params[1]+"/"+params[2]);

    # seems to cause a view refresh
    # $state.transitionTo 'criteria', {criteria:params[1], q:params[2]}, {inherit:false}

    updateModel(...)
```

And, what is I think is happening is that I am triggering the `$stateProvider` code:

```
angular.module 'afmnewApp'
.config ($stateProvider) ->
  $stateProvider
  .state 'main',
    url: '/'
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html'
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
    controllerAs: 'main'
  .state 'criteria',
    url: '/criteria/:criteria/:q'
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html'
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
    controllerAs: 'main'
```

One possible clue is that with the code below if I load e.g. http://afmnew.herokuapp.com/criteria/cuisine/italian then the view refreshes as you navigate, whereas if I load http://afmnew.herokuapp.com/ there are no refreshes, but no URL updates instead. I don't understand why that is happening at all.

Comment: I haven't studied this article in any depth yet, but you may find it interesting. https://weluse.de/blog/angularjs-seo-finally-a-piece-of-cake.html

Comment: Unfortunately this is about pre-rendering, whereas my question is about navigating a SPA in an SEO-friendly manner

Comment: Have you seen ui-sref? also reloadOnSearch parameter in the state config?

Comment: reloadOnSearch looks like it might help, but is it part of ui.router?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on our previous discussions, I want to give you some idea, how to use `UI-Router` here. I believe, I understand your challenge properly... There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQUU6F?p=preview). If this not fully suites, please take it as some inspiration

*DISCLAIMER: With a plunker, I was not able to achieve this: http://m.amsterdamfoodie.nl/, but the principle should be in that [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQUU6F?p=preview) similar*

So, there is a state definition *(we have only two states)*

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          '@' : {
            templateUrl: 'tpl.layout.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
          },
          'right@main' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.right.html',}, 
          'map@main' : {
            templateUrl: 'tpl.map.html',
            controller: 'MapCtrl',
          },
          'list@main' : {
            templateUrl: 'tpl.list.html',
            controller: 'ListCtrl',
          },
        },
      })
    .state('main.criteria', {
        url: '^/criteria/:criteria/:value',
        views: {
          'map' : {
            templateUrl: 'tpl.map.html',
            controller: 'MapCtrl',
          },
          'list' : {
            templateUrl: 'tpl.list.html',
            controller: 'ListCtrl',
          },
        },
      })
}];
```

This would be our main **`tpl.layout.html`**

```
<div>

  <section class="main">

    <section class="map">
      <div ui-view="map"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="list">
      <div ui-view="list"></div>
    </section>

  </section>

  <section class="right">
    <div ui-view="right"></div>
  </section>

</div>
```

As we can see, the main state does target these nested views of the main state: **'viewName@main**', e.g. `'right@main'`

Also the subview, `main.criteria` does inject into **layout** views.

*Its url starts with a sign **^** (`url : '^/criteria/:criteria/:value'`), which allows to have `/` slash for main and not doubled slash for child*

And also there are controllers, they are here a bit naive, but they should show, that on the background could be real data load (based on criteria).

The most important stuff here is, that the PARENT `MainCtrl` creates the **`$scope.Model = {}`**. This property will be (thanks to inheritance) shared among parent and children. That's why this all will work:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope)
{
  $scope.Model = {};
  $scope.Model.data = ['Rest1', 'Rest2', 'Rest3', 'Rest4', 'Rest5'];  
  $scope.Model.randOrd = function (){ return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); };
})
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams)
{
  $scope.Model.list = []
  $scope.Model.data
    .sort( $scope.Model.randOrd )
    .forEach(function(i) {$scope.Model.list.push(i + " - " + $stateParams.value || "root")})
  $scope.Model.selected = $scope.Model.list[0];
  $scope.Model.select = function(index){
    $scope.Model.selected = $scope.Model.list[index];  
  }
})
```

This should get some idea how we can use the features provided for us by UI-Router:

- [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)
- [Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only)
- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

Check the above extract [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQUU6F?p=preview), in [the working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQUU6F?p=preview)

Extend: new plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8PqvOR?p=preview)

If we do not want to have map view to be recreated, we can just omit that form the child state def:

```
.state('main.criteria', {
    url: '^/criteria/:criteria/:value',
    views: {
      // 'map' : {
      //  templateUrl: 'tpl.map.html',
      //  controller: 'MapCtrl',
      //},
      'list' : {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.list.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl',
      },
    },
  })
```

Now our map VIEW will be just recieving changes in the model (could be watched) but view and controller won't be rerendered

ALSO, there is another plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/y0GzHv?p=preview which uses the `controllerAs`

```
.state('main', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
      '@' : {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.layout.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main',        // here
      },
      ...
    },
  })
.state('main.criteria', {
    url: '^/criteria/:criteria/:value',
    views: {
      'list' : {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.list.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'list',      // here
      },
    },
  })
```

and that could be used like this:

```
<h4>{{main.hello()}}</h4>
<h4>{{list.hello()}}</h4>
```

The last plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/y0GzHv?p=preview)

Comment: Quick question: is it vital to create the Model in MainCtrl - I have been using a shared Factory so far?

Comment: Simon, please, that does not seem to me serious. I want to help, but you are giving me link to version with minified Javascript? that does not work. You should see that I wanted help. So try to adjust, extend my plunker to reproduce the issue. I can also re-engeneer your life app, but... *(that's a bit over Q&A on SO)*... Anyhow, I wanted to give you a hint as promised. I created pretty sophisticated plunker. If you want me to do more, please, make it easy for me. I understand if you do not need my assitence any more... Does it make sense?

Comment: OK, forgive the previous question. My main interest is not to refresh the map, but to have the controller delete and recreate markers as the model changes (caused by clicks on the 'right' panel). I modified your plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9atRT1?p=preview and added a console.log message each time the MapCtrl is loaded, which is equivalent to the view reloading (I think), and it fires all the time. That's a concern for me, but it may be due to the fact that I am keeping the model in a Factory (my first comment above)

Comment: Will come to you later... promise

Comment: I'm currently working on the idea that I need to get the map itself into the main view, but have the markers created by a subview

Comment: I am really sorry, to not reply now, will be available later today... That Idea seems to me correct. Will updated plunker, which won't be using map on child...

Comment: I have updated my plnkr so that it emulates what I want, and have been able to implement that on my site :-) Only thing I have lost now is the controllerAs which just seemed to be blocking everything on my site

Comment: OK, I am in. So the plunker is still http://plnkr.co/edit/9atRT1?p=preview ? what should I check? I am fully ready to assist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67242/discussion-between-simon-h-and-radim-kohler).

Answer (score 16):

This is an example of the way to go if I understand correctly:

```
$state.go('my.state', {id:data.id}, {notify:false, reload:false});
//And to remove the id from the url:
$state.go('my.state', {id:undefined}, {notify:false, reload:false});
```

From user **l-liava-l** in the issue https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/64

You can check the `$state` API here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: awesome thx John - fyi this doesn't work on the old router - it worked like a charm after I upgraded to `angular-ui-router/0.2.18` (was on 0.2.13)

Comment: No problem. It seems that there are some "secondary" problems with this, you can check in the github issue I point in the answer. But if I am not mistaken it should have been addressed in 1.x releases of UI-Router

Comment: This works just fine clicking the link, but if I go forward/back on browser, it reloads the view

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the problems I was referring to in my comment. I didn't have the chance of checking if that still happens in the 1.0 alpha version (the most recent version as for today)... is that the case?

Answer (score 2):

you can use scope inheritance to update url without refreshing view

```
$stateProvider
            .state('itemList', {
                url: '/itemlist',
                templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/item/ItemListTemplate.html',
                controller: 'ItemListController as itemList'
                //abstract: true //abstract maybe?
            }).state('itemList.itemDetail', {
                url: '/:itemName/:itemID',
                templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/item/ItemDetailTemplate.html',
                controller: 'ItemDetailController as itemDetail',
                resolve: {
                    'CurrentItemID': ['$stateParams',function ($stateParams) {
                        return $stateParams['itemID'];
                    }]
                }
            })
```

if child view is inside parent view both controllers share same scope.
so you can place a dummy (or neccessary) ui-view inside parent view which will be populated by child view.

and insert a

```
$scope.loadChildData = function(itemID){..blabla..};
```

function in parent controller which will be called by child controller on controller load. so when a user clicks

```
<a ui-sref="childState({itemID: 12})">bla</a>
```

only child controller and child view will be refreshed. then you can call parent scope function with necessary parameters.

Comment: Thanks. In fact i ended up wrapping the map in a div with a controller but not linked to a view. In not using scope inheritance but have all the key data in a service that the controller can of course access

Answer (score 0):

The short answer ended up being do **not** put the map inside a view that changes. The accepted answer provides a lot more detail on how to structure a page with sub-views, but the key point is not to make the map part of the view but to connect its behaviour to a view that does change and to use a Controller to update the market icons.